# tumah and tahara davening takanas Ezra

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

i once heard that once zera is dried it is no longer tameiand not considered a problem for davening etc. does anyone know if this is true? for example if somebody bumped into or sat on dried zera would they be able to daven after or do they have to wash their clothes in case any got on or would they have to toivel etc.?

Comment: no longer soil and you can davening without prior washing.  Tum'at is not the purpose of the takanat Ezra but Baal Keri. Despite that,  it's true that the shichvat zera dried in no longer tame.